# Can I catch header setting in terminal

Tags: php, phpunit

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: application/json");
var_dump(headers_list());
```

If I use browser it shows

```
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<b>array</b> <i>(size=2)</i>
  0 <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.12'</font> <i>(length=24)</i>
  1 <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'Content-Type: application/json'</font> <i>(length=30)</i>
</pre>
```

But if I execute the file in terminal it's echo

```
array(0) {
}
```

Can I get header result from command line, I want to do the unit test.

Comment: Try to add -q when execute with php in terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you have xdebug installed, and therefore you should be able to use `xdebug_get_headers()` in place of `headers_list()`, which should work from the terminal/your unit tests

Comment: I know xdebug solution, but I really want to find out PHP native solution, in case the user environment does not installed it but want to do the test